# Can't Read XML with Service Principal

Tags: databricks

I have the following spark configuration in my Databricks Cluster.

```
    fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret {{secrets/YYY/ZZZ}}
    fs.azure.account.auth.type OAuth
    spark.databricks.delta.preview.enabled true
    fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint https://login.microsoftonline.com/YY/oauth2/token
    fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider
    fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id BBB
```

Reading the `XML` file as text works:

```
spark.read.text('abfss://yyy@xxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/abc.xml')
```

Reading the `XML` file as xml fails with `Failure to initialize configurationInvalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key`:

```
spark.read.format("xml").load("abfss://yyy@xxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/abc.xml")
```

How can I read a XML file without using an account key?